Excel Formula Combine MATCH , INDEX, COUNT

I have 2 sheets. the first one called 'Employee' the second 'Database'
In 'Employee' sheet in cell 'AO3' I want to bring the sum of comment ' Meet Expectation' how much declared for 'x' employee based on 'Database' sheet.
But since there are many employees , I want this code bring only the information related to 'x' employee matching cell 'S3' which is let say 'Roberto' and match also comment 'Meet expectation' then this code will go to 'Database' sheet and look matching for 'Roberto' and count how many 'Meet expectation' were declared, and give just a value '3 times or 1 time or 0 '
I tried this Code , but not working at all
=IFERROR(INDEX(COUNTIF('Database'!$E$2:$E$1000,AO3),MATCH(E3,'Database'!$B$2:$B$1000,0), MATCH(AO3,'Database'!$E$2:$E$1000,0),"")


You can try this formula:
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(Database!$E:$E;Employee!AO$2;Database!$B:$B;Employee!$E$2);"")

